# MongoDB query for field in embedded document in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document where stock prices are saved in an embedded document within an array in MongoDB.  I need to get one stock price, depending on the date, and both display in the template and also use in further calculations.

I have a [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/jkzmpT7huYdDEFeNX/Datepicker%20and%20Closing%20Prices) with an example.  The helper to get the stock price starts at /client/app.js line 25, using the code from @Hakan Kose's answer.  Not sure how to change the last line though (`console.log` won't work here).

For 2015-12-01, the query should return `117.34`.

```
{
  ticker: "AAPL",
  valuationDate: "2015-12-01",
  closingPrices: [
    {date: "2015-12-01", close: "117.34"},
    {date: "2015-12-02", close: "116.28"},
    {date: "2015-12-03", close: "115.20"},
    {date: "2015-12-04", close: "119.03"}
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easyly with;

```
Valuations.findOne({_id:this._id}, function(data){
   data.closingPrices.forEach(function(closingPrices){
       if(closingPrices.date === valuationDate){
           console.log(closingPrices.close)
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Novice question here - your last line uses `console.log` but I'm trying to display the value in the template and use in a calculation.  I added your code to the Meteorpad but how can I change the last line accordingly?

Comment: Change your question based on your new question. add how you call the function and where you want it to show so I can change my answer based on that.

Comment: Thanks, I added detail, along with a Meteorpad with full example.